# Unable to get service when registering unbound generics in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, .net-core

When registering the unbound generic with a class I cannot get the service injected into my objects:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<,>), typeof(GetItems));
//Exampe class 
public class GetItems : IGetItems<GetResultsParms, GetResults> {}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
requires registering an open generic implementation type
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Is it an exception or a compiler (or code-analysis) message? If it's an exception, what is its stack-trace? Are you using a custom backend for `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`?

Comment: It is an exception. I'm using the integrated one: asp net core DI. I'm able to register regular classes with their interfaces fine.

Comment: Unrelated tip: Don't name classes, interfaces, and structs after verbs (only methods and delegates should be named after verbs).

Comment: That's a great tip, that was just a quick example. Everything works fine if I do the following: services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<GetResultsParms, GetResults>), typeof(GetItems));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine open-generic-interfaces with an closed-generic implementation.

Here's an example of why:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<,>), typeof(GetItems));

class GetItems : IGetItems<GetResultsParms, GetResults> {}

class Consumer {

    public Consumer( IGetItems<String,Int32> getter )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Supposing this works, then `Consumer` will be given `IGetItems<GetResultsParms, GetResults>`, which is demonstrably incompatible with its request for `IGetItems<String,Int32>`.

You need to rethink your interface design.

I assume `IGetItems` is an interface that represents a single data-retrieval operation that's meant to be generic over different types (e.g. one consuming class would request `IGetItems<CustomersParams,CustomersResults>` and another would do `IGetItems<OrdersParams,OrdersResults>`).

To do that, you need a custom factory - not a specific implementation type. However you need to provide more detail about how `IGetItems` is meant to work, and how the values/instances for for the type parameters are created.

Alternatively, if each possible type-argument for the type-parameters is known at compile-time, just register each possible combination:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<CustomersParams,CustomersResults>), typeof(CustomersGetter));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<OrdersParams,OrdersResults>), typeof(OrdersGetter));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IGetItems<ProductsParams,ProductsResults>), typeof(ProductsGetter));
```

...which can be done more succintly using the generic overloads:

```
services.AddTransient< IGetItems< CustomersParams, CustomersResults>, CustomersGetter >();
services.AddTransient< IGetItems< OrdersParams, OrdersResults>, OrdersGetter>();
services.AddTransient< IGetItems< ProductsParams, ProductsResults>, ProductsGetter>();
```

Comment: Is there an example where I can see how to create a custom factory?

Comment: @ShakHam There are plenty of tutorials on the web for using factories with Dependency Injection.