# Dependency injection for open type generic interface and closed type class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a generic interface **IViewModelService.cs**

```
public interface IViewModelService<T> where T : class
{
    public Task<T> Get(); // returns a view model
}
```

Which is implemented by two different View Model Services that I assume are closed types:

```
public class HomeViewModelService : IViewModelService<HomeViewModel>
{
    public HomeViewModelService()
    {
        // Dependency injection for Db Context here
    }

    public async Task<HomeViewModel> Get()
    {
        //requires some async _dbContext logic
        return new HomeViewModel(); // for testing purposes
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ProfileViewModelService : IViewModelService<ProfileViewModel>
{
    public ProfileViewModelService()
    {
        // Dependency injection for Db Context here
    }

    public async Task<ProfileViewModel> Get()
    {
        //requires some async _dbContext logic
        return new ProfileViewModel(); // for testing purposes
    }
}
```

Been researching on dependency injection, and I wanted to know how would I be able to implement these services into Startup.cs. I tried these:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IViewModelService<>), typeof(HomeViewModelService)); 

// ERROR: Open generic service type 'IViewModelService`1[T]' requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter 'descriptors')'
```

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IViewModelService<HomeViewModelService>), typeof(HomeViewModelService)); 

// ERROR: Implementation type 'HomeViewModelService' can't be converted to service type 'IViewModelService`1[HomeViewModelService]'
```

```
services.AddScoped<IViewModelService<HomeViewModelService>, HomeViewModelService>(); 

// ERROR: This type cannot be used as a type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method. 
// There is no implicit reference conversion from HomeViewModelService to IViewModelService<HomeViewModelService>
```

Comment: `HomeViewModelService : IViewModelService<HomeViewModel>` so `.AddTransient<IViewModelService<HomeViewModel>, HomeViewModelService>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 services.AddScoped<IViewModelService<HomeViewModel>, HomeViewModelService>();
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811218/unable-to-get-service-when-registering-unbound-generics-in-net-core) to know more

Answer (score 2):

I tried as below to accomplish dependency injection for open type generic interface.if you don't want to implement the intereface and regist the services too much times  ,you could try this

```
public class HomeViewModel
    {
        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            id = 1;
            name = "name1";
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    public class AnotherViewModel
    {
        public AnotherViewModel()
        {
            id = 2;
            name = "name2";
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Modified the codes of service class:

```
public interface IViewModelService<T> where T : class
    {
        public T Get(); 
    }
    public class ViewModelService<T> : IViewModelService<T> where T : class
    {
        public ViewModelService()
        {
            
        }

        public  T Get()
        {
            Type t = typeof(T);
            if(t==typeof(HomeViewModel))
            {
                HomeViewModel homeviewmodel = new HomeViewModel();
                return (T)(object)homeviewmodel;
            }
            else if (t == typeof(AnotherViewModel))
            {
                AnotherViewModel anotherviewmodel = new AnotherViewModel();
                return (T)(object)anotherviewmodel;
            }           
            return default(T);
            
        }
    }
```

regist it in startup:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IViewModelService<>), typeof(ViewModelService<>));
```

in controller:

```
public IActionResult Test1([FromServices] IViewModelService<HomeViewModel> viewModelService)
        {
            var homeviewmodel = viewModelService.Get();
            return Ok();
        }
        public IActionResult Test2([FromServices] IViewModelService<AnotherViewModel> viewModelService)
        {
            var anotherviewmodel = viewModelService.Get();
            return Ok();
        }
```

Test Result:
[image]